# X509Certificate2 does not load properly in asp net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate2

I have the following code:

```
if (usuCli.certificado != null && usuCli.senha_crt != null)
{
         try
         {
               X509Certificate2 certificado = new X509Certificate2(usuCli.certificado, usuCli.senha_crt);
               CertificadoValidade.Text = (certificado == null) ? "<b style=\" color: red;\"> O certificado deste cliente venceu ou é inválido. </b>"
                                                                : "<b style=\" color: red;\"> O certificado deste cliente vence no dia: " + new X509Certificate2(usuCli.certificado, usuCli.senha_crt).NotAfter.ToString() + "</b>";
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
               CertificadoValidade.Text = "<b> O certificado deste cliente venceu ou é inválido. " + ex.Message + " </b>";
         }
}
```

Note: usuCli.certificado is the certificate in an byte[], as its saved in my DB, usuCli.senha_cert is the certificate password, a string. Project is an ASP.NET page with 4.5 Framework.

So... when i execute it in my tests(Visual Studio 2019), it loads properly (the line with the NotAfter)

When i execute it in my ISS server (a Windows Server 2016), my clients can't load their certificates properly (the catch line). I know this because i see specifically in black, instead of red.

By all i can know, the DB data is properly loaded (they load all their stored properties, such as name, etc), only the certificate messes up, thus my main suspect beign X509Certificate2.

Any ideias how i can solve this?

Update: my .NET framework on the machines that the certificate loaded properly is 4.8. I downloaded and installed in my server, with no results.
HOWEVER, i find out that some certificates don't work, but some do. 
But, even weirder, in my debbuger and some local machines, both load and sign just fine. But running the application from my server, it results in the above situation: some certificates work, some dont.

Could it be some Filezilla config that i'm not aware?

------Hex of the certificate that doesnt load-------------------------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---

------Hex of the certificate that does load------------------------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---

Comment: Is the version of Net the same on machine that works and machine that does not work?  I've seen a number of cases where updating software that SSL (including X509) doesn't work.  The new version of Net is defaulting to 64 bit encryption and your certificate is probably 32 bit.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: And what exception message says?

Comment: "System could not find specified file", which should be impossible, because i load it as byte[] from DB

Comment: Both machines are 64 bit. How can i discover the bits of the certificate?

Comment: Just added the same framework that my other machines use and work (.NET framework 4.8, in this case) to my server. Didn't worked

Comment: Set aside c# for now. Can you manually put the certificate on the machine and open it interactively (by double clicking)?

Comment: Yes, in my testing machines, my developer machine and in my server(even in my client's machine). The certificate is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, i solved it. In the IIS, I need to set "Load User Profile" to True in the application pool's advanced settings to be able to load some certificates.